# When testing implementation, is the approach I take a common one, or am I doing it wrong?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Ok so I have the below module, it returns a list of User Id's from a table, where the ids match a regular expression:

```
public sealed class UserIdListRetriever : IUserIdListRetriever
{
    private readonly EntityFrameworkClass _databaseConnection;

    public UserIdListRetriever(EntityFrameworkClass databaseConnection)
    {
        _databaseConnection = databaseConnection;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Retrieve()
    {
        var salesAgents = _databaseConnection
            .tblAccounts
            .Select(account => account.UserId)
            .Distinct();

        var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\\)(.*?)(?=\:)");

        return (from agent in salesAgents
                .AsEnumerable()
                select regex.Match(agent)
                into match
                where match.Success
                select match.Value.ToUpper())
                .OrderBy(match => match);
    }
}
```

And here is the interface:

```
public interface IUserIdListRetriever
{
    IEnumerable<string> Retrieve();
}
```

I keep reading that I should test behaviour, not implementation but thing I care about here is whether or not my class returns an accurate list of user id's.

I could create a mock implementation of an IUserIdListRetriever, and maybe assert in my unit test that I get back an IEnumerable of string that isn't null, but that won't test whether or not my LINQ is correct, or whether or not my Regex is correct which doesn't feel that useful.

I feel as though those are the two things that are important here (whether or not I have my LINQ correct, and whether or not my Regex is correct) and I end up with test classes like this:

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
etc etc

namespace myNamespaceTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UserIdListRetrieverTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void UserIdListRetrieverReturnsAccurateInformation()
        {
            var databaseConnection = 
                new EntityFrameworkClass("connection;string;");

            var userIdListRetriever = new UserIdListRetriever(databaseConnection );

            var userIds = userIdListRetriever.Retrieve();

            /*
             * I put a breakpoint here, 
             * and run the same query in SQL Management studio 
             * to make sure I have the same results
            */
             Assert.IsTrue(userIds.Any());
        }
    }
}
```

This feels very wrong, but from my point of view I find this the most useful as it still allows me to test quickly (although not that quickly) that this module is doing what I want it to do.

I have lots of modules like this, and my code is still modular and testable, but I only find the tests useful when I spend a bit of time running the unit tests manually, stepping through each one and running queries against the database manually to verify that the information my data retrieval modules are giving me back are what I expect to see. After this I can say with confidence that every module in my codebase does what I want it to do.

I don't know anybody else who works this way, which is usually a bad sign (am I wrong, or is everybody else wrong?). Can somebody more knowledgeable explain where I am going wrong here and explain how they test classes like the one above, in a way that they can run tests quickly and those tests are automated, but they can say with confidence that each of their modules has the intended behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally hold that if it involves the database, it's not unit testing. With that said, I've looked at this same problem for several years, but I can't offer you a more elegant solution to test your data retrieval statement.

I would note that this code does not abide by the Single Responsibility Principle - it retrieves data from an EF source, and then further filters it. What you can do is split this code into 2 separate pieces: one to retrieve the list, and a second to examine the list for strings matching your regex. Then, you can easily set up unit tests to verify that the regex is working as expected.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense, to make the data retrieval tools as minimalist as possible (all they do is grab data from the database and nothing else) then apply any further logic in a seperate module. That way I can mock the data access part, while testing further logic in an automated way! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This approach leads to Integration tests not Unit tests. What if you run your Unit tests on a Build server where no connections are available to the Database.

First you must under stand if you're using the actual resources then This would be an Integration test not Unit test.

So if you want to test the database connection integrity you're doing right. But if you just want to test your filter logic. Then you must refactor your method Retrieve() into two parts.

**part i)** Returns the exact results returned from database.

**part ii)** Test filter operation on result.

This way you can mock your returned result from DB. Then test the method of filterning to ensure that on a given DB result it's working fine.

e.g.

```
        public IEnumerable<string> Retrieve()
        {
            return _databaseConnection.tblAccounts.Select(account => account.UserId).Distinct();
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> GetMatchingItems(IEnumerable<string> salesAgents)
        {
            var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\\)(.*?)(?=\:)");

            return (from agent in salesAgents
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    select regex.Match(agent)
                        into match
                        where match.Success
                        select match.Value.ToUpper())
                    .OrderBy(match => match);
        }
```

Comment: Most of what people call "unit testing" is really integration testing. Testing a single method that calls no other code is very rare indeed. What changes is the scope of testing up to some fairly large chunks. Build servers that run tests need to have access to databases. Q-E-duh.

Comment: Because most of the people have wrong thinking for taking Unit test and Integration testing as same. If you need to test integrity of the system then Go for Integration test that what you wanted to do I guess. But First write Unit tests -> then Integration tests -> then Acceptance/System tests. This will make your system robust.

Comment: You completely missed my point. Invoking a method under test also, implicitly, tests all the methods that it invokes directly or indirectly. Invoking some purist ideology about what is and isn't unit testing only leads to confusing people who actually have to build tests in the real world. In your definition of unit testing, you could not possibly test a method that takes part in JPA, uses annotations or invokes libraries. At some point, it becomes a decision on what constitutes a unit.

Comment: Nope, I didn't said that. You can write unit tests but your code must be open to inject dependencies which is known as Testable code. for e.g. Your code is testable as you can inject fake object for DB dependency. My point is, if you want to write unit test then don't bind them with real dependent object as a standard of Unit testing. If you write Integrated test and run them on Build server you can assume how much time it'll take if you have bulk of Integration tests written.

Comment: Thanks very much, your answer was helpful as were @BobDalgleish 's comments, cheers to you both!